# What is open set classification in data mining?

Tags: data-mining

What exactly is open set classification in data mining? Is it a synonym or another word for one of these classification types?

-Binary Classification 
-Multi-Class Classification 
-Multi-Label Classification 
-Imbalanced Classification

I have been browsing the web for a while but can't seem to find any implementation of open set classification in either Python or Matlab. Can anyone provide good resources on how to implement open set classification?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this researh paper](https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0238302#:%7E:text=Open%20set%20classification%20(OSC)%20is,an%20incorrect%20label%20%5B3%5D.)

> Open set classification (OSC) is the ability for a classifier to reject a novel input from classes unseen during training rather than assigning it an incorrect label

Take for example, a model that has been trained to recognize cats through images. When we introduce images to the data set test, the model may make a mistake when tested with an image that was not included in the training set, although the model still performs well when it comes to images of known classes. OSC role comes to its ability to classify the irrelevant image as "Unknown" instead of "Cat".

Here's a [github code sample](https://github.com/LincLabUCCS/Open-set-text-classification-using-neural-networks) in python, it might be helpful to you.